# Why the method getLastLocation() get a location out of date sometimes?

Tags: android, gps, maps, location, android-location

Im using the new api to get location. But even with this new api my device get the location out of date. This method (getLastLocation()) is getting a location out of date. If the wifi is onits ok, it gets the atual location. But when the wifi is off, it gets a old location. How the app of maps of Google can get the location so fast?

This is the class I'm using:

```
public class NewGPSTracker implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {


private LocationRequest lr;
private LocationClient lc;
Location location;
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;
Context context;    
public int res = 0;
boolean connected;  


public  NewGPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    lr = LocationRequest.create();
    lr.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    lr.setInterval(5000);       
    lr.setFastestInterval(1000);
    lc = new LocationClient(context, this, this);   

    sp = context.getSharedPreferences("GPS", 0);
    editor = sp.edit();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {              
    if (connected && location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        }


    }

}



@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i("NewGPSTracker", "Google Play Services Conectado.");
    lc.requestLocationUpdates(lr, this);
    connected = true;           

    location = lc.getLastLocation();        
    if (connected && location != null) {    

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();    
        Log.i("Location", ""+latitude + " "+longitude);

    }       
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {     
    Log.e("NewGPSTracker", ""+arg0);
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}   


public void connect(){
    lc.connect();
}

public void disconnect(){
    lc.disconnect();
}       

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {

}


public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265722/locationclient-does-not-update-getlastlocation-on-emulator

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to know why the location reported when WiFi is off is out of date. The `LocationClient.getLastLocation()` method will only ever return "the best most recent location currently available". This means that when you are not using WiFi - one of two things may happen.

1. The device has no connectivity. This would be the case when using devices that do not have mobile data, such as the WiFi only models of the Nexus 7. In this scenario, the `getLastLocation()` method would return the last location it had from when it was last connected. This results in an old location being returned when the method is called.
2. The device is using a mobile network to get the location. Usually, to reduce the amount of mobile data used - locations are fetched to a lower accuracy and/or fetched less frequently. This means that when a new location is obtained, it may be deemed as not "the best most recent location". There are multiple factors such as time between locations being obtained, and accuracy of data collected that affect whether the "best most recent location" is updated.

For more information about the `LocationClient` class, and ways to use locations within an application, you can look at these sources from the Android developer site.

- https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

As description about the method [getLastLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#getLastLocation%28%29) says,

This method returns the best most recent location currently available.

If a location is not available, which should happen very rarely, null will be returned. The best accuracy available while respecting the location permissions will be returned.

This method provides a simplified way to get location. It is particularly well suited for applications that **do not require an accurate location** and that do not want to maintain extra logic for location updates

it simply means that,it may not try to retrieve new location for you at same time.

For better understanding,I would suggest you to go through this video session:
[Beyond the blue dot](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325337477)

**EDIT :**

After getting connected to location services,You can request location updates by using method [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#requestLocationUpdates%28com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener%29).

Kindly download the sample app from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html).

Comment: So, if the method, sometimes, get a old location, how can I get the atual location?

Comment: then y are you doing `getLastLocation` again? you have already requested,so you will definitely get updated location inside `onLocationChanged` method.